# RegEx for extracting YouTube IDs and time sequence

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I would like extract the video ID (string) and (if available) the sequence integer, from Youtube URLs.

#### Input

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doXt8abo3IY
https://youtu.be/FIqBQ-CxAfQ
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlOSMl33CNA&t=0m4s
```

I tried this pattern but it doesn't work:

```
^https?://.*(?:youtu.be/|v/|u/\w/|embed/|watch?v=)([^#&?]*).*$
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: @Emma, it's done :) Thank by advance Emma!

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close but you didn't escape the slashes properly. Though this may differ per language, I'm not sure. Anyways, here's the working regex I got:

`^https?:\/\/.*(?:youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch?v=)([^#&?]*).*(?>t=([0-9]+)).*$`

See https://regex101.com/r/9EjjN4/1 for testing and ability to export to different languages

Answer (score 0):

If we only wish to match those cases listed in our question, then we could likely simplify our expression to something similar to:

```
(?:.+v=|.+\.be\/)(.+?)($|&.+)
```

Since, we might not really want to validate the URLs, that I'm guessing. However, if we like to add more boundaries, we can do so.

Here, we join two conditions using logical ORs, in a non-capturing group:

```
(?:.+v=|.+\.be\/)
```

Then, we collect our desired IDs using a capturing group:

```
(.+?)
```

Finally, we add a right boundary:

```
($|&.+)
```

and this would also work for the right boundary (using non-capturing group):

```
(?:$|&.+)
```

---

This expression might be simple to modify, if any other URLs come up, we just add new boundaries using logical ORs in the left and right sides of our desired IDs.

[image]

```js
const regex = /(?:.+v=|.+\.be\/)(.+?)($|&.+)/gm;
const str = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doXt8abo3IY
https://youtu.be/FIqBQ-CxAfQ
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlOSMl33CNA&t=0m4s`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/ccHkBz/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ccHkBz/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If we wish to capture the `t` variable, we can extend our expression, maybe to something similar to:

```
(?:.+)(?:\.be\/|v=)(.+?)(?:&|$)(?:t=)?(.+)?
```

It might be much better, if we design individual expression for each task, otherwise, we might be facing future problems. For example, it would be much better if we could design one separate expression for `.be`, one for `v=` and one for `t=`.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bP6XCE/1/)

```js
const regex = /(?:.+)(?:\.be\/|v=)(.+?)(?:&|$)(?:t=)?(.+)?/gm;
const str = `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doXt8abo3IY
https://youtu.be/FIqBQ-CxAfQ
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MlOSMl33CNA&t=0m4s`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but I can't retrieve the sequence ("t")